# How to add vte terminal widget in GTK3?

Tags: python, application-development, quickly, gtk3

I'm trying to add `vte` widget in my application and the examples I've found use `.fork_command()` to execute a command in that widget.
But according to

http://developer.gnome.org/vte/0.26/VteTerminal.html#vte-terminal-fork-command

it was deprecated and it's recommended to use `fork_command_full()`. Which needs eight mandatory arguments. Haven't they heard the "**defaults**" word? I've been able to construct lines that work somehow:

```
pty_flags = vte.PtyFlags(0)
terminal.fork_command_full(pty_flags, "/home/int", ("/bin/bash", ), "", 0, None, None)
```

Yes, I know about the enums, I just hope that I'm doing this completely wrong and there is a much easier way. Do you know any?

P.S. I'm using `quickly` with the default `ubuntu-application` template.

P.P.S. The import line is `from gi.repository import Vte as vte`

Comment: you have that long line a bunch of times or just once?

Comment: just once right now but I want to add them dynamically in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here a basic example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gi.repository import Gtk, Vte
from gi.repository import GLib
import os

terminal     = Vte.Terminal()
terminal.spawn_sync(
    Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT,
    os.environ['HOME'],
    ["/bin/sh"],
    [],
    GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD,
    None,
    None,
    )

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
win.add(terminal)
win.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: How can I catch/handle/recover from a user submitting 'exit' in the terminal? On exit would I need to spawn a new vte terminal? or perhaps just spawn a new shell inside the terminal?
Additionally, can you link to documentation on how to manipulate the vte terminal, eg opening bash on click of a gtk button press?

Answer (score 6):

Building on ADcomp's answer to address wanting to add them dynamically in the future, I think you might want to subclass Vte.terminal.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gi.repository import Gtk, Vte
from gi.repository import GLib
import os

class MyTerm(Vte.Terminal):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(MyTerm, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.spawn_sync(
            Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT,
            os.environ['HOME'],
            ["/bin/sh"],
            [],
            GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD,
            None,
            None,
            )

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
bigbox = Gtk.Box()
win.add(bigbox)
bigbox.add(MyTerm())
bigbox.add(MyTerm())
win.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thanks :) `__init__(self, command)` would be even nicer, I'll try this later.

Comment: @int_ua - more what you wanted?  i thought you were just looking to embed a term from the context of the question

Answer (score 6):

Since VTE 0.38, `vte_terminal_fork_command_full ()` has been renamed to [`vte_terminal_spawn_sync ()`](https://developer.gnome.org/vte/unstable/VteTerminal.html#vte-terminal-spawn-sync). So if you are using newer versions, you have to change [@ADcomp's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/155739/274080) into the following:

```
terminal.spawn_sync(
    Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT,
    os.environ['HOME'],
    ["/bin/sh"],
    [],
    GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD,
    None,
    None,
    )
```

Comment: Thanks - I am using ruby-gtk bindings but indeed that change I did not notice, so this is useful.

Answer (score 5):

[Vte.Terminal.spawn_sync](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Vte-2.91/classes/Terminal.html#Vte.Terminal.spawn_sync) is deprecated. So if you are using Vte version 0.48 or above, use [Vte.Terminal.spawn_async](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Vte-2.91/classes/Terminal.html#Vte.Terminal.spawn_async) instead. Here is an example of a Vte.Terminal.spawn_async:

```
terminal.spawn_async(
    Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, # Pty Flags
    os.environ['HOME'], # Working DIR
    ["/bin/bash"], # Command/BIN (argv)
    None, # Environmental Variables (envv)
    GLib.SpawnFlags.DEFAULT, # Spawn Flags
    None, None, # Child Setup
    -1, # Timeout (-1 for indefinitely)
    None, # Cancellable
    None, # Callback
    None # User Data
)
```

Comment: This is my first AskUbuntu post :D

Comment: It is even useful for non-python; for example, ruby code is almost the same as the python code, just with some syntax difference e. g. GLib.SpawnFlags would be Glib::SpawnFlags - so this information is useful even for non-python folks. (I do use python too, though.)